# Positive integers $x, y, z$ satisfy the equation $x^2+y=z^2+z$, how to pr0ve that $x\leq y$

Tags: calculus

I have come across the following question. There are positive integers $x, y, z$ that satisfy the equation $x^2+y=z^2+z$. How to prove that $x\leq y$?
I tried to start from the following $x^2 +y + \frac{1}{4}=(z+\frac{1}{2})^2$ but got stuck here. Could someone be so kind and give me any hint?

Thanks

Greg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(y-x)=(z+x+1)(z-x)$$

If $x>y$ then $x>z$. Therefore $x^2+y\geq z^2+2z+1+y> z^2+z$

Comment: Both solutions are great. EEE was quicker. I'm wondering what was the thinking process for both of you? Is the proof by contradiction so visible in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Assume $y<x$ . Then, we have $$x^2<x^2+y<x^2+2x+1=(x+1)^2$$

So, the number on the left side is between two consecutive squares.

For the number on the right side , we have $$z^2<z^2+z<z^2+2z+1=(z+1)^2$$ hence it is also between two consecutive squares.

Since the numbers coindice, the surrounding squares must coincide as well, hence we have $x=z$ implyinf $y=z$.

So, we get $y=x$ which is a contradiction to $y<x$